# How do I launch and configure Google Maps API for Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-api

I copied the code that worked well and pasted it to another computer. 
But, why did not it work on another computer.

1. The emulator version of the computer that worked was `API 26`.
    However, if you turn on the `API 27`, `API 25` emulator and `API 19` mobile phone 
    from another computer, it will stop at the same time as it runs.

2.When you create a project,
     I also registered google_maps_key through the Google homepage in the 
     **google_maps_api.xml** file.

3.I have also adapted the package name of the `java` source.

What else do I need to set?

I would appreciate if you can tell me what I need.

I did (`Ctrl + G`) and attached the picture below.

[image]
MapsActivity.java

```
    package com.example.ggavi.myapplication;

    import android.location.Address;
    import android.location.Geocoder;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
    import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

    //import java.io.IOError;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

        private EditText et;
        private Button button;
        private GoogleMap mMap;
        LatLng startingPoint;
        final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        /**
         * Manipulates the map once available.
         * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
         * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
         * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
         * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
         * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
         * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
         */
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
            button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    String str = et.getText().toString();
                    List<Address> list = null;
                    try {
                        list = geocoder.getFromLocationName(
                                str, // 지역이름
                                10); //  읽을 갯수
                    }catch(IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    String total_str = list.get(0).toString();
                    System.out.println(":"+total_str);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),total_str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    int position=total_str.indexOf("latitude");
                    String str1 = total_str.substring(position+9); //위치 받아옴(latitude)
                    //  System.out.println(">>"+str1);
                    int position_comma = str1.indexOf(",");
                    String latitude = str1.substring(0,position_comma);
                    System.out.println("latitude>>"+latitude);
                    int position2=total_str.indexOf("longitude");
                    String str2 = total_str.substring(position2+10); //위치 받아옴(latitude)

                    int position_comma2 = str2.indexOf(",");
                    String longitude = str2.substring(0,position_comma2);
                    System.out.println("longitude>>"+longitude);

                    startingPoint = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latitude),Double.parseDouble(longitude));
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(startingPoint).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(startingPoint,15));
                }
            });




            // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


        }
    }
```

activity_maps.xml

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10">
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="8"
            >
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="검색어를 입력하세요."/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="검색"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            tools:context="com.example.icarus.myapplication.MapsActivity" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

error code:

```
11/06 21:14:21: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.ggavi.myapplication/com.example.ggavi.myapplication.MapsActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Connected to process 4038 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.ggavi.myapplication-1/lib/x86
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.ggavi.myapplication, PID: 4038
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ggavi.myapplication/com.example.ggavi.myapplication.MapsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                      at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
                      at android.location.GeocoderParams.<init>(GeocoderParams.java:50)
                      at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:83)
                      at android.location.Geocoder.<init>(Geocoder.java:95)
                      at com.example.ggavi.myapplication.MapsActivity.<init>(MapsActivity.java:29)
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: I found the title incorrect and corrected it.

I was writing a question yesterday and there was a bug where the snippet did not close, so I tried to write another question. But the previous contents were backed up, and the wrong contents were uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> final Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
> ```

You're trying to use your `Activity` as a `Context` too early when initializing this field. Move the initialization `new Geocoder(this)` to `onCreate()` or later in the activity lifecycle.

Comment: I did not have any additional answerers so I accepted your answer.
I'm sorry I can not raise your score because I'm low on the mark.